# Convergence of sequence uneven/even

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Given is:

$
(a_n )_{n=1}^x $ with (x = infinite)

and with
$ a_n = \frac{1*3*...*(2n-1)}{2*4*6...*(2n)} $

I have to show if the sequence is convergent or not:

I thought about showing that the sequence is

1.) monotonous (rising)

2.) bounded ( $a_n < 1$ )

and then it's proven that it is convergent? Is this 'enough' ?

Comment: $∞$ = `\infty`.

Comment: Yes, showing a sequence is monotonically increasing and bounded above is enough to show convergence.

Comment: I think the sequence is decreasing.  $a_{n+1} = a_n\frac{2n+1}{2n+2} < a_n$. Decreasing and positive is also enough.  You  should be able to find a theorem in your notes.

Comment: $0\leq\frac{1.3.5\cdots(2n-1)}{2.4.\cdots(2n)}\leq \frac{1.3.5\cdots(2n-1)}{\sqrt{1.3}.\sqrt{3.5}.\cdots(\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n+1)})}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$

Comment: Though it might be hard to show that this sequence increases: At each step you multiply by $\frac{2n-1}{2n} < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$0\leq\frac{1.3.5\cdots(2n-1)}{2.4.\cdots(2n)}\leq \frac{1.3.5\cdots(2n-1)}{\sqrt{1.3}.\sqrt{3.5}.\cdots(\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n+1)})}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$